# Traefik seems to ignore the rules of the routers (bug?)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

Today, I'm calling for your help, because I'm encountering routing problems with **Traefik** (v2.4) and I have the impression that it's a bug with the latter.

I use Docker v20.10.2 and Docker Compose v1.25.0 on Debian 10 (Buster)

I'm looking for these redirections :

```
www.mywebsite.com
    |____main-wordpress:80
www.mywebsite.com/blog
    |____blog-wordpress:80
```

So I have a **docker-compose.yml** composed like this (extract) :

```
---
version: '2.4'

services:

  # *---------------------------*
  # | WordPress (for main site) |
  # *---------------------------*
  main-wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.6
    hostname: main-wordpress
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=main-mysql
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${MAIN_MYSQL_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${MAIN_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${MAIN_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/wordpress/main:/var/www/html/
      - ./volumes/wordpress/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/01_user.ini
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
       - main-mysql
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # Redirect HTTP ➔ HTTPS
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-web.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-web.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-web.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
      # Route : HTTPS ➔ HTTP (WordPress)
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-websecure.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-websecure.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.services.webapp.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-websecure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt-1"
      # Enable "middlewares"
      - "traefik.http.routers.main-wordpress-web.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
    restart: unless-stopped

  # *-----------------------*
  # | WordPress (for /blog) |
  # *-----------------------*
  blog-wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.9.8
    hostname: blog-wordpress
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=blog-mysql
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${BLOG_MYSQL_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${BLOG_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${BLOG_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/wordpress/blog/:/var/www/html/
      - ./volumes/wordpress/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/01_user.ini
      - ./volumes/wordpress/blog/.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
       - blog-mysql
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # Redirect HTTP ➔ HTTPS
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-web.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`)) && PathPrefix(`/blog`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-web.priority=10000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-web.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
      # Route : HTTPS ➔ HTTP (WordPress)
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-websecure.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`)) && PathPrefix(`/blog`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-websecure.priority=10000"
      - "traefik.http.services.webapp.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-websecure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt-1"
      # Enable "middlewares"
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog-wordpress-web.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
    restart: unless-stopped

  # *-------------------------*
  # | Traefik (reverse-proxy) |
  # *-------------------------*
  traefik:
      image: traefik:2.4
      hostname: traefik
      command:
        - "--api=true"
        - "--api.dashboard=true"
        - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
        # Entry points
        - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
        - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
        # Access logs
        - "--accesslog=true"
        - "--accesslog.filepath=/access.log"
        - "--accesslog.bufferingsize=200"
        # ACME (Let's Encrypt)
        - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt-1.acme.httpchallenge=true"
        - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt-1.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
        - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt-1.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}"
        - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt-1.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt-1.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" # For DEV purpose
        - "--log.level=DEBUG" # For DEBUG purpose
      ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        # Route : HTTPS ➔ HTTP (Traefik itself)
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-websecure.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`)) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard/`))"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-websecure.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-websecure.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-websecure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt-1"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicAuth.users=${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_AUTH}"
        # Redirect HTTP ➔ HTTPS
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-web.rule=(HostHeader(`www.mywebsite.com`) || HostHeader(`mywebsite.com`)) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard/`))"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-web.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
        # Enable "middlewares"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-websecure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-web.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        - ./volumes/traefik-certificates:/letsencrypt
        - ./volumes/traefik-access.log:/access.log
      restart: unless-stopped
```

When there is **only one WordPress in use**, **everything works fine**, routing is done as expected.

On the other hand, **when both WordPress are running**, Traefik **does a kind of "load balancing" between the two**, as if they were running on top of each other.
I looked into Traefik's access-logs and that's exactly what happens, **requests are split between the two containers regardless of the original URL**.

I don't understand this behavior even though I have well **defined priorities to avoid this behavior** according to the documentation and the rules seem good to me.

Do you think I missed something? I've been looking for 2 days and I don't see :/

Thanks to those who will help me solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i get the solution from **Kevin Pollet** on GitHub :
[solution from GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lubNb.png)

To make it simple, in my case, I was using the same webapp for both WordPress, so Traefik does a balancing in this case.

To stop this behaviour it was enough to make two different webapps. Since then, everything works as expected.

If anyone else has the same problem ...